# where should be i586-mingw32msvc-pkg-config?

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compiling, libav

when i configure libav in ubuntu, there's an warning like this

> WARNING: i586-mingw32msvc-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.

here's my configure code.

> ./configure --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i586-mingw32msvc- --arch=x86 --prefix=/usr/local/win32 --enable-memalign-hack --disable-gpl --disable-avisynth --disable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-encoders --disable-muxers --disable-network --disable-devices --enable-shared

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem.

in my case, it should be **/usr/bin**

i586-mingw32msvc-pkg-config file is must be excutable. (chmod +x i586-mingw32msvc-pkg-config)